# Sharepoint online calling search API using Rest API

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, sharepoint-rest-api, search-api

I was tried many times, I am not able to calling rest Api call, when i was tried with ajax call then it's work fine, but when i tried with rest api then it's not working.

so can you help me to find solution for that.

I have attached image of ajax call and rest api's error.

[image]
(AJAX call Image)

[image]
(Rest Call Image)

[image]
(Error Image)

I have tried to found many sites, but not getting proper answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint Online allows you to perform searches using the SharePoint Search REST API. You can use the REST API to execute search queries and retrieve search results programmatically. Here's how you can call the SharePoint Search API using the REST API:

```
// Replace these with your actual values
var siteUrl = "https://your-sharepoint-site-url";
var searchQuery = "your search query";
var accessToken = "your-access-token";

$.ajax({
  url: siteUrl + "/_api/search/query?querytext='" + searchQuery + "'",
  type: "GET",
  headers: {
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken
  },
  success: function (data) {
    // Process the search results (data.d.query.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults)
  },
  error: function (error) {
    // Handle errors
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, It's working.